# Why doesn't this CoffeeScript/JavaScript set the properties of created object?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've the following two CoffeeScript class definitions. I expected them to the same behavior, but they don't. In particular accessing `A` on instances of `DoesNotWork` is undefined.

```
fields = ["A","B","C"]

class DoesNotWork
  constructor: () ->
    _.each(fields, (f) -> @[f] = ko.observable(''))

class DoesWork
  constructor: () ->
    @A = ko.observable('')
    @B = ko.observable('')
    @C = ko.observable('')
```

the above code compiles to

```
var DoesNotWork, DoesWork, fields;
fields = ["A", "B", "C"];
DoesNotWork = (function() {
  function DoesNotWork() {
    _.each(fields, function(f) {
      return this[f] = ko.observable('');
    });
  }
  return DoesNotWork;
})();
DoesWork = (function() {
  function DoesWork() {
    this.A = ko.observable('');
    this.B = ko.observable('');
    this.C = ko.observable('');
  }
  return DoesWork;
})();
```

What newbie JS subtly am I missing?

Comment: It does work... it just doesn't do what you wanted it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'this' in the anonymous function passed to _.each is bound to the anonymous function, not the parent object. _.each does allow passing a context object so that this will be bound properly though

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#each

so pass a ref to the object you are trying to bind to in the 3rd arg of each:

```
class ShouldWorkNow
  constructor: () ->
    _.each(fields, ((f) -> @[f] = ko.observable('')),this)
```

Comment: The function should be in `()`.  It should be: `_.each(fields, ((f) -> @[f] = ko.observable('')), this)`

Comment: @Rocket: Thanks, I just copied the code in the example. Fixed.

Comment: One small correction: `this` isn't bound to the anonymous function by default, but rather to the global context, as when you write `func.call null, ...`.

Comment: You really rarely need `_.each` in Coffee Script.  I highly recommend `for/in` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another solution (arguably the most readable and efficient) is to skip `_.each` and instead use CoffeeScript's `for...in` iteration:

```
for f in fields
  @[f] = ko.observable ''
```

You could even postfix the loop to make it a one-liner:

```
@[f] = ko.observable('') for f in fields
```

Remember that loops in CoffeeScript don't create context or affect scope; only functions do.

Comment: both answers are great choices. A shame there isn't a collection.each built into coffeescript, much like in Ruby. underscore does a fine job of patching this style but coffeescript comprehensions are pretty slick. I guess I prefer the loop mechanic up front as opposed to trailing (old c habits)

Comment: Right, CoffeeScript doesn't modify prototypes. You could use CoffeeScript in conjunction with [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/) if you want an `each` method on your arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Craig's answer is correct, but an alternative solution is to define your anonymous function as a [bound function](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#fat_arrow). In this case, that would let you write

```
_.each(fields, ((f) => @[f] = ko.observable('')))
```

The `=>` binds the function to the context in which it's defined, so that `this` always means the same thing in the function no matter how it's called. It's a very useful technique for callbacks, though in the case of `_.each`, it's a bit less efficient than passing `this` in.

You could do the same thing using Underscore by writing

```
callback = _.bind ((f) -> @[f] = ko.observable('')), this
_.each(fields, callback)
```

but `=>` saves you a lot of typing!